# Write dbt test for positive values

Tags: dbt

Is there an easy way to write a test for a column being positive in dbt?

`accepted_values` doesn't seem to work for continuous variables.

I know you can write queries in `./tests` but it looks like an overkill for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [`dbt_utils.expression_is_true`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#expression_is_true-source)

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: model_name
    tests:
      - dbt_utils.expression_is_true:
          expression: "col_a > 0"
```

Comment: Solid answer. Slight addition: if you are adding a test like this to a specific column in the model then you wouldn't include the column name. So the test here would simply be `expression: "> 0"`

Answer (score 12):

Previous answer is correct. Another option is [accepted_range](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#accepted_range-source):

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: model_name
    columns:
      - name: user_id
        tests:
          - dbt_utils.accepted_range:
              min_value: 0
              inclusive: false
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the dbt_utils suggestion is good, the only reasonable alternative I can think of is writing a custom schema test:

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/writing-custom-schema-tests/

But why bother when you can just use expression_is_true
@jake

Answer (score 2):

Another way with [dbt-expectations](https://hub.getdbt.com/calogica/dbt_expectations):

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: model_name
    columns:
      - name: user_id
        tests:
          - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_between:
              min_value: 0
              strictly: true
```